# Subquery in INSERT works in SQL but not PDO

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a new dataset into a MySQL table `tab` with external data, but also with data from another table `otherTab` using the others' table primary key and another condition. However, it could be that the requested row simply does not exist (anymore) or the result set is empty due to a mismatch in the other supplied data. All columns are forbidden to be NULL.

My first attempt was:

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, extid1, extid2, value)
SELECT 1,
       (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 12 AND data = 'TXT'),
       (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 34 AND data = 'JPG'),
       1234
```

but the problem with it is that a returned empty result set is cast to the type of the column in `tab`, leading to a `0` as entry data.

The query shall be efficient and avoid unnecessary querying. This is how I achieve it with four subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, extid1, extid2, value)
SELECT 1,
       (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 12 AND data = 'TXT'),
       (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 34 AND data = 'JPG'),
       1234
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 12 AND data = 'TXT')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 34 AND data = 'JPG')
```

Is this, or a `JOIN`, or a transaction with a temporary variable and `IF` construct the only option?

I tried with other constructs, e.g. `(SELECT IFNULL(SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 12 AND data = 'TXT', NULL))` to enforce `NULL` or even a string into the target column, but it also gets casted to a `0` or some value instead.

**EDIT**
Here is the code for dbFiddle:

code

```
CREATE TABLE `tab` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `seUuid4` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `rxUuid4` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(16)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `otherTab` (
  `uuid4` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `lgUuid4` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(16)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

ALTER TABLE `otherTab`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(`uuid4`);
ALTER TABLE `tab`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tab_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rxUuid4`) REFERENCES `otherTab` (`uuid4`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tab_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`seUuid4`) REFERENCES `otherTab` (`uuid4`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

INSERT INTO `otherTab` (uuid4, lgUuid4, data) VALUES
(UNHEX("22224444aaaa49c782408b2fe8c4dee0"), UNHEX("00001234aaaa4444aaaa432187654321"), "JPG"),
(UNHEX("11113333aaaa49c782408b2fe8c4dee0"), UNHEX("12340000bbbb6666bbbb432187654321"), "TXT");

INSERT INTO tab (id, seUuid4, rxUuid4, text)
SELECT
    1,
    (SELECT uuid4 FROM otherTab WHERE lgUuid4 = UNHEX('00001234aaaa4444aaaa432187654321') AND data = 'JPK' LIMIT 0,1),
    (SELECT uuid4 FROM otherTab WHERE lgUuid4 = UNHEX('12340000bbbb6666bbbb432187654321') AND data = 'TXT' LIMIT 0,1),
    'some text'
```

This interestingly works exactly as expected. I verified my code (PHP - I know..) and the PDO prepared statement fires out **exactly** the same command, but it gets inserted as `INSERT INTO tab (id, seUuid4, rxUuid4) VALUES (1, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000, 0x00000000000000000000000000000000, 'datatext');` while the SQL client and phpMyadmin deliver the expected `cannot insert null` error message.

I am off to check the PDO options - sorry for the confusion :-)

**EDIT2**: changed the title name and will leave it open if someone has an idea by chance. Otherwise, I will ask the PHP/PDO experts.

Comment: Can it be that extid1 has a default value 0? you dn't need a slect fr only ne row, that is used to insert a bunch of rows.

Comment: No, the `extid1` and `extid2` fields are set to have no default value and cannot be NULL (actually, these are BINARY(16) fields, but should not make a difference).

Comment: please post the create table  for tab  binary(16) was a suprise

Comment: I tried you insert with you data, but i can't reproduce it see if you can make a fiddle like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/40

Comment: Added the dbFiddle code which executes correctly in MySQL. Seems to be an issue with the interfacing PHP/PDO driver.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix your problem, with the insert

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, seUuid4, rxUuid4, text)
SELECT
    1,
   IFNULL ((SELECT  uuid4 FROM otherTab WHERE lgUuid4 = UNHEX('00001234aaaa4444aaaa432187654321') AND data = 'JPK' LIMIT 0,1) IS NULL,0),
    (SELECT uuid4 FROM otherTab WHERE lgUuid4 = UNHEX('12340000bbbb6666bbbb432187654321') AND data = 'TXT' LIMIT 0,1),
    'some text';
```

but this gives following error

> Schema Error: Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`tab`, CONSTRAINT `tab_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`seUuid4`) REFERENCES `otherTab` (`uuid4`))

Which means that you must enter there a uuid, which is exists

Comment: Unfortunately not: it just returns a 0/1 in dbfiddle and in phpmyadmin, leading to your stated error message. As I said above: the `INSERT` works directly in SQL as expected, but somehow does not throw an error in PHP/PDO. Your suggested code here for example leads to an inserted value of `0x3100000...00` instead of an error.

Comment: in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/41 i can't enter any value, because if the error. PDO should not have have an impacted

Answer (score 0):

If the expected result is to avoid inserting anything in case either of the two subqueries returns nothing, then just move them to the `FROM` clause:

```
INSERT INTO
  tab (id, extid1, extid2, value)
SELECT
  1
, txt.id
, jpg.id
, 1234
FROM
  (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 12 AND data = 'TXT') AS txt
, (SELECT id FROM otherTab WHERE id = 34 AND data = 'JPG') AS jpg
;
```

This way the subqueries will act as derived tables in a cross join.  The result of a cross join between two sets is an empty set if at least one set is empty.  And if both return a row each, then you get a single-row result set with two columns, which you can reference using the aliases assigned: `txt.id`, `jpg.id`.  And that is exactly what the main select does.